# Generate random array with random numbers between two values, including negative ones with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Creating and array like

```
random_num = np.random.randint(10,20)
arr_rand = np.random.randint(random_num, size = (4,2))
```

works normally, but how do I make the minimum value a negative number?
I get the two errors:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-7a3b85248cc6> in <module>
      1 random_num = np.random.randint(-10,20)
----> 2 arr_rand = np.random.randint(random_num, size = (4,2))

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint()

_bounded_integers.pyx in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32()

ValueError: low >= high
```

Also, they should preferrably be floats. The only other way I know how to do it is with the usual randn that generates values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your existing code doesn't do what you think it does, by the way. `10` and `20` aren't the bounds on your random array. You're generating a random upper bound, and then generating an array of numbers between 0 (inclusive) and that random upper bound (exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `np.random.randint` twice. This will work:

```
np.random.randint(-10,20,(4,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for `np.random.uniform(-10,20)`. Here is the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html).